# Multiplicative Function Property

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

Suppose $f$ is an arithmetic function. Does the property $f(1) = 1$ if $f$ is multiplicative? Or is it only when $f$ is completely multiplicative?

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is multiplicative, then $f(n)=f(1\cdot n)=f(1)f(n)$.  Therefore $f(1)=1$.

Comment: Provided $f$ is not identically $0$.

Comment: Ah, yes, I forgot about that possibility.